# In MySQL, data is still accessible after moving the partition directory

Tags: mysql, partitioning, partition

My partition schemes looks something like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    PARTITION BY RANGE (integer_field) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (100) DATA DIRECTORY = '/my_location/partitions/p0'  ,
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (200) DATA DIRECTORY = '/my_location/partitions/p1' ,
    PARTITION p_other VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) DATA DIRECTORY = '/my_location/partitions/p_other'
);
```

As expected, data is being stored properly into the partitions, and into the proper directory.

**Problem**:

Now when I remove/move the directory from the location, like `mv /my_location/partitions/p0  /some_other_location/` , the directory gets moved successfully, but data is still query-able from MySQL shell, even after restarting the shell.

**My Solution:**

To get it working as expected, after moving the directory including the `.ibd` file, I had to drop the partition explicitly:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION p0;
```

This removed the partition from the scheme as required and also cleared the data, verified it by again querying the same data.

**Assumption / Understanding:**

I think that MySQL is caching the data, not sure where and why exactly, which makes it query-able even after partition directory is moved away. Definitely cache is not at connection level as I closed and reopned the shell.

**Question**:

I expected the data to disappear as soon as the directory `p0` was moved away. Is it really necessary to run the drop partition statement each time the directory is moved?

**Constraints**:

It is sure that `p0` directory is moved away only when the `p0` partition is no more used. So there will not be any more data required to enter into existing `p0` partition

*MySQL: 8.0.19*

Comment: This is just how linux reacts it when you [move open files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29225). But you should really describe what you are trying to do here, as, assuming  there is a proper way to do what you want to do, *this* really doesn't sound like the right way to do it.

Comment: @Solarflare Just trying to archive that particular partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows or not?

Did you restart mysqld?

`mv` on Linux (and close relatives) is really a "rename".  And, assuming the target is on the same filesystem, that rename can even involve a different directory.

When a program (eg, `mysqld`) has a file (eg, the table partition) "open" `mysqld`, it has control over it -- even if you run off to a shell and `rm` the file!.

I suspect that when you restart mysqld (for any reason, including reboot), the "data directory" will become messed up.

Aside from the filesystem's partitioning, you must tell MySQL when you "archive" a partition.  Read up on "transportable tablespaces" *for the version you are using*.  Here's a writeup for 5.6; 5.7 has some improvements.

I don't see the advantage of using a *filesystem* partition.  With "transportable tablespaces", you can disconnect a *MySQL* partition from a `PARTITIONed` table.  This turns the partition into a table.  Then that table can be deleted, renamed, copied, etc, without impacting the partitioned table.  Search for "transportable" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint ; there are some links.

Comment: Windows or not? : No. Linux

Did you restart `mysqld`? No. And not planning to possibly. 

Also as mentioned in the comments, I am actually trying to archive that particular partition. Just need to know if that's the correct way of doing it? Or is there any other way?

Comment: @Rakmo - I added a little to my Answer.  I'm not sure where you are heading, but maybe that will help.

Comment: I think that's something in the correct direction. Checking it. :)

Comment: That is some truely correct approach. I am looking more into tablespaces. Can you elaborate one more step so I can mark this answer as correct? Please add flow for how to take backup of the partition directory properly (archiving) and then drop it from MySQL. What's the correct way of doing that?

Comment: @Rakmo - I added a paragraph.  Sorry, I don't have the details off the top of my head.

Comment: Credits given to this answer, which led me to the right solution. I am adding the approach I followed in new answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Rick James and @Solarflare, moving around the `ibd` file while it is still in Open state for MySQL does behave in weird way, and tablespaces gets messed up. Following their guidance, and the MySQL Docs, here is the final approach that successfully worked for me (Possibly, the right way to do it):

1. Lock the table

   ```sql
   FLUSH TABLES my_table FOR EXPORT;
   ```

   This prevents any update/write operation to the desired table and makes the `ibd` file safe to copy. Additionally, this creates a `.cfg` file. These steps are very well explained in [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html)
2. Once the table is "Locked", copy the `.ibd` file to the desired location for archival. PS: Do not move / delete the source file yet.

   ```sh
   cp -r /my_location/partitions/p0  /some_other_location/
   ```
3. Unlock tables to be able to alter the partition

   ```sql
   UNLOCK TABLES;
   ```
4. Drop the required partition safely. This also informs the tablespaces.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION p0;
   ```

   Note that this statement leads to removal of partition, plus the data corresponding to that partition.